# Get device or simulator information runtime for SOAP web services

Tags: android, iphone, soap, codenameone

I have here a small issue with Codenameone when calling a `SOAP` web service from the device.
As you may know, `SOAP` web services have their own way of encoding the http requests. These encoding rules are also different wether you use `SOAP` 1.1 or 1.2.

When I run in the simulator, its seems like v1.2 is used, and this requires a certain way of specifying the http headers for the service to work.

When you are on a device (iPhone here), then it is switched to `SOAP` 1.1 and thus, the http headers needs to be encoded differently (soap action, content type).

So the question: in my code, how can I figure in which environment am running, simulator, or real device? And while at it, if we ever need to do specific logic of this sort based on device nature, how can we make this check?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Display.getInstance().getPlatformName()
```

to return the name of the platform you are running on.

If it is running on an iPhone it will return "ios". 
I did a quick test and saw that it also return "ios" in the emulator.

Hope this helps